# AngularJs | Don't show page until all directive htmls loads successfully

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I create a couple of directives in my angularjs application which loads external html template (from another url). When I navigated to that page, the whole binding works but the directive html load didn't happen quick enough and thus it shows an empty space in between. Is there any way, I can ask angularjs to wait for the external html resources to load and then show the page view.

I have made a sample app where I created one simple directive and load external html to it with dynamic wait time (passed in query string for the template)

[sample code](http://codepen.io/manishrawat4u/pen/bpybem)

```
app.directive('ccDd1', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {},
        link: function() {

        },
        templateUrl: 'http://testdirective.apphb.com/default?waittime=3'
    };
});
```

Can someone help me on that.

Comment: I tried your code at [codepen](https://codepen.io/manishrawat4u/pen/bpybem). I don't see any extra space covered by the directive until it's loaded. Try using `{{vm.test}}<cc-dd1></cc-dd1>{{vm.test}}`  in html.

Answer (score 0):

ensure that you adding angular.min.js before your script and i'm wondering why you script is immediate function, it should be normal script, so remove :

```
(function() {
 //your js code
// do other stuff}()); and only set your code
```

Comment: The ngCloak directive is used to prevent the Angular html template from being briefly displayed by the browser in its raw (uncompiled) form while your application is loading. Use this directive to avoid the undesirable flicker effect caused by the html template display. Read this :https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak

Answer (score 0):

You can put the directive ngCloak on the parent div of your directives. That can remove your blink effect.

[ngCloack documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak)